# c++ formating error with cstrings when using tolower

Tags: c++, cstring

Hi so I am trying to take a cstring and make it lowercase, but when I am printing the cstring at the end I am getting a weird format box where some of the letters should be. Do anyone have any ideas?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{ 
    int i=0; 
    char* str="TEST"; 
    char c; 
    char* cstr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    while (str[i]) 
    { 
        c = str[i]; 
        c = tolower(c);
        strcat(cstr, &c); 
        i++; 
    } 

    cout << cstr << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There's something ironic about using `char *` and `new` and not using `std::string` class.  See `std::transform` for converting an `std::string` to lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `strcat` incorrectly. The second parameter is not a null-terminated string.

You really don't need to call `strcat` at all. Just write directly to the output string:

Try:

```
  while (str[i])
  {
    c = str[i];
    c = tolower(c);
    cstr[i] = c;
        i++;
  }
  cstr[i] = 0;
```

or, equivalently:

```
while(str[i])
{
  cstr[i] = tolower(str[i]);
  i++;
}
cstr[i] = 0;
```

Comment: I thought that strcat seemed out of place.  Nicely job putting that in simple easy to read code.

Comment: seg faults- at str[i] = tolower(str[i]

Comment: @trev9065 - yes, that is a different bug. I'll add it to the description.

Comment: -1 It seg faults because this code is trying to modify a string constant. I'll undo my -1 when this is fixed/addressed. :-)

Comment: @Rob: The OP is not trying to modify a read-only string. You are! :-)

Comment: @Emile - yes, I misread the OP's program. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The answer is also wrong about why strcat is "needless." The OP *is* concatenating to the end of the string.

Comment: @Rob: Cool. +1 fillerfillerfiller

Comment: @Rob: You forgot to assign a null terminator at the end of `cstr`.

Comment: @trev9065: Do you now see why `std::string` is preferable to old school c-strings? Even experienced folks have a hard time getting c-strings right the first time. :-)

Comment: @Emile yeah, I do but I am reading in the cstring using a old api and then hashing it so cstring's in general are easier to do all this

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` expects a **null-terminated** `char*`, so by giving the address of a local `char` you are invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Additionally, `new char[std::strlen(str) + 1]` does not initialize the array to `0`s, meaning `cstr` won't be properly null-terminated either; adding `()` to the `new[]` causes the array to be value-initialized.

Try this instead:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char const* str = "TEST";
    char c[2] = { };
    char* cstr = new char[std::strlen(str) + 1]();
    std::size_t i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        c[0] = static_cast<char>(std::tolower(str[i++]));
        std::strcat(cstr, c);
    }
    std::cout << cstr << std::endl;
    delete [] cstr;
}
```

Comment: This seems overly complex for a simple solution.

Comment: @Tyler Ferraro : The OP's code was overly complex, I simply fixed their bug. The OP didn't ask what a better approach would be, they asked why their code wasn't working. For purposes of edification, it is *at least* as helpful to explain how/why they were using `strcat` incorrectly as to take a different (read: "better") approach that doesn't tell them why their code was broken. Downvote **not** warranted imo.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of strcat is supposed to be a null terminated string, not the address of a single character. strcat isn't appropriate for this use.

```
int main ()
{
    const char* str="TEST";
    char* cstr = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    cstr[strlen(str)] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; ++i) {
        cstr[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
    cout << cstr << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "TEST";
    std::string cstr;

    for (std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin(); it!= str.end(); ++it)
        cstr.push_back(tolower(*it));

    std::cout << cstr << std::endl;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
```

...

```
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(cstr), tolower);
```

Comment: noticed codepad wouldn't resolve the transform overload - no time to figure it out. Reverting to previous version of answer